# IE11 and nomodule attribute

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Based on this site, IE11 doesn't support nomodule attribute:

[IE and nomodule attribute](https://caniuse.com/#search=nomodule)

Now I'm loading a script like this inside a page:

```
<script defer="defer" nomodule src="script.js"></script>
```

If I load the page in IE11, I expect that because IE11 doesn't support **nomodule** attribute, it should load the script. But it doesn't.

IE11 loads the script only if I remove **nomodule** like this:

```
<script defer="defer" src="script.js"></script>
```

Why is that?
Is IE11 now supporting **nomodule** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to test the issue with sample code below and I find that IE 11 is loading the script.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script defer="defer" nomodule src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
sample page
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
alert("js file loaded...");
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

I suggest you to clear your cache and make a test with this example on your side to check the result. Let us know, if issue still persist on your side. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Reference:

[: The Script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)